# Is FreeNAS 8 ready for production? or Any sugg. for a free fileserver?

Tags: ubuntu, file-server, truenas, openfiler

I need a free fileserver solution mixed Mac/Win environment for the small print shop I work at. We are having problems with using SMB on OS-X (file w/o extensions are getting lost and weird SMB lag with 10.6).

We are currently running the Fileserver with Windows 2000 Server on a PowerEdge 850.

Being a print shop, the art department is run on OS-X. The rest of the shop is running WinXP (2-3 macs, 5 win) and 5 servers (2k3 and 2k8). We don't have an Active Directory or LDAP.  It mainly stores fonts, logos, software ISOs, Acronis cold images, and job archives.

> • FreeNAS 8 seems to offer a lot out
>   of the box that would help our shop:
>
> Time machine support    AFP for the
>   macs    Easy for others to use if I am
>   out on Vaca or sick    ZFS snapshots
>   would be cool, but not necessary
>
> • Ubuntu server can be configured for
>   all but ZFS. However, i'm not
>   extremely comfortable with bash.
>
> • Openfiler seems to be rock solid.
>   However, the lack of AFP means that
>   i'm back to the same issues  with
>   Server2000.

Any ideas? I would love to run FreeNAS, but I'm not sure if this is unwise. I could make an openfiler VM on my ESXI and backup FreeNAS to that, in case of a software issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/47021/is-freenas-reliable

Comment: Actually, from what I understand FreeNAS 8 is a rebuilt from scratch. I can't seem to find a whole lot regarding production use with 8.0

Comment: The interface is but the underlying important stuff is still FreeBSD-release. The reason you haven't seen much about FreeNAS-8.x is that it is still pretty new.

Comment: Oooo, thanks for the clarification, I thought the new FreeBSD kernel changed a lot behind the scenes.

Comment: @kce As I understand this is about **FreeNAS 8** and the other question is **old** and answered when there were **older versions** of FreeNAS so I think is not a duplicate and I find it quite interesting. Anywa the other tread was a useful reading also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you: 1) Try to isolate and understand what the *actual* problem is with the interaction between your Mac OS X clients and your Windows 2000 Server file shares. While it's probably a good idea to replace your Windows 2000 Server as it is no longer supported, you might not solve the problem. Maybe the switch is bad? Maybe is a problem with the way OS X handles the SMB protocol? Regardless, it would be a shame to replace your file server and not solve this problem (and likely introduce a few new ones along the way). Maybe start [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/88/slow-network-speeds-what-should-i-check) with your troubleshooting efforts.

2) Get some old hardware and run FreeNAS. Do some testing and see how you like it...see how stable it feels to you. From this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/47021/is-freenas-reliable) it seems there are plenty of people running FreeNAS in a production environment. But the terms "stable" and "production" can have vastly different meanings and requirements depending on your environment. A little testing here will probably go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success with [Lefhand's (now HP)](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/va/92113/reviews) free VM SAN. Its free and well tested.